# Is there any generalization of Riemann Mapping theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Given any two regions in complex plane when can we say they are conformally equivalent? I mean does there exists some "complex-geometric" invariant which determines whether two regions are conformally equivalent or not. Obviously topological invariant won't work as both are at least diffeomorphic. Can you please provide some intuition why $B(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$ is not conformally equivalent with any annulus with some positive radius? (I am not asking for proof). I understand some angle "should" be distorted because any angle preserving and orientation preserving map is holomorphic. Orientation preserving still understandable but I am not getting where is angle distortion happening? 
   Thank you.

Comment: by B(0,1)\ {0} I meant open unit disc with origin deleted.

Comment: There are more shapes and sizes than just annuli $B(0,R)\setminus \overline{B(0,r)}$, but those are conformally equivalent iff they have the same ration $\frac rR$. (Especially, the punctured disk is not equivalent to an annulus with positive $r$ ... IIRC, one can map all regions to "standard" regions consisting of a disk with arc-shaped slits; and those representative shapes are then quit characteristic (there's a choice what to pick as "outer hole", though, and of course only up to rotation)

Comment: To add on to the previous comment: this only works for domains whose complement had finitely many connected components (no complements of Cantor sets allowed!), and there are a variety of choices of "canonical domains". The best presentation of this I know is in Conway's "Complex Variables II", where he devotes a chapter to conformal mappings.

Comment: Thanks ...I shall check that chapter ..